# how to install erratic-robot on the indigo?

Tags: ros, erratic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can not install this package.I use the ubuntu14.04.
And someone can teach me how to install it? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229487/how-to-install-erratic-robot-on-the-indigo?/) by [littlestar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26326/littlestar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Captcha](https://answers.ros.org/users/14366/captcha/) on 2016-03-18**:
It looks like it's not yet supported by Indigo [Erratic ROS Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/erratic_robot). Yet, can you post the error or the installation log preventing its installation?

**Comment by [littlestar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26326/littlestar/) on 2016-03-19**:
Finally, I download this package zip and use catkin_make to compile it and it look like can work.
Thank you.

**Comment by [Captcha](https://answers.ros.org/users/14366/captcha/) on 2016-03-19**:
Please mark your question as answered. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same question.
I download this package zip and relese them,then i put the package in src in my work space.
but i have no idea to do next.
So can you help me ? thank you very much.
is it worked to just use catkin_make in my work space(catkin_ws) as you said ?

---

Originally posted by [warmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26409/warmer/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0